# Why additional drivers don't let me select one driver

Tags: ati, graphics

When I open additional drivers it shows a list of propietary drivers but it won't let me change them. I click apply changes and it simply goes back to nouveau. I don't mind nouveau but it causes graphical glitches in my steam games. Steam also won't detect drivers.
My graphic card is Radeon 6330M

Comment: I always though that 'nouveau' is a NVIDIA-only driver.

Comment: Nouveau is nVdia, not AMD so you are mixing something up that should not be mixed together.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal by pressing Ctrl+ Alt+ T.

Then run this command.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

Comment: Thx but i don't want the first one.I want the 3 rd one but when i apply changes go back to the first one but i selected 3 rd one